# Pasar valores de un DataGridView a ComboBox y TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo el siguiente conflicto, al intentar pasar los valores de cada renglon de mi datagrid a los otros contorles de mi form ya que unicamente me carga los valores del primer row y requiero que segun el renglon sobre el que de clic el usuario se cargue la informacion del primero, segundo, tercer renglon etc, dejo el codigo que estou usando para pasar dichos valores, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
public void ValidaArticulosBD()
{
    try
    {
        if (txtFolio.Text != "")
        {
            folioText = txtFolio.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            folioText = "";
        }
        if (folioText!="")
        {
            dtBuscaDetalle = objConsultas.MuestraDetalleArticulos(folioText);
            if (dtBuscaDetalle.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvArticulos.DataSource = dtBuscaDetalle;
                ArticuloDGV = dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                CantidadDGV = int.Parse(dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                preciounitarioDGV = dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                if (preciounitarioDGV.StartsWith("$"))
                {
                    preciounitarioDGV1 = preciounitarioDGV.TrimStart('$');
                    preciounitarioDGV2 = double.Parse(preciounitarioDGV1);
                }
                detalleDGV = dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                DetalleDB = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvArticulos.DataSource = "";
                DetalleDB = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}

private void dgvArticulos_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ValidaArticulosBD();
        if (ArticuloDGV!="")
        {
            dtArticulos1 = objConsultas.BuscaArticulos(ArticuloDGV);
            if (dtArticulos1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                cmbIngresArticulo.Enabled = false;
                cmbIngresArticulo.DataSource = dtArticulos1;
                cmbIngresArticulo.ValueMember = "Art_ID";
                cmbIngresArticulo.DisplayMember = "Art_Descripcion";
            }
        }
        if (CantidadDGV > 0)
        {
            txtIngCantidad.Text = CantidadDGV.ToString();
        }
        if (preciounitarioDGV !="")
        {
            txtIngPU.Text = preciounitarioDGV2.ToString();
        }
        if (detalleDGV!="")
        {
            txtDescripcion.Text = detalleDGV;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: No termino de entender cual es tu problema. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y explicar mas claramente cual es el problema que tienes con el código que nos muestras y cual es el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: Tengo una ventana windows forms para ingresar ordenes de servicio, en esta ventana tengo 3 RadioButton para buscar, editar y guardar ordenes, al elegir la opcion buscar debo cargar 2 DataGridView uno de los cuales me muestra el detalle de los articulos que contiene la orden de servicio mostrada, al dar doble clic sobre cada renglon debo cargar otros contorles de mi form como ComboBox y TextBox con la información de cada renglon de mi DataGridView Articulos pero al dar doble clic sobre cada uno, unicamente puedo cargar los otros controles con la información del primer renglon en mi DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Conozco una manera, es útil y bastante sencilla, primero que nada, involucra dos eventos:
- dataGridView1_CellClick
- dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick
El primer método hace que cuando selecciones una fila, cual sea (dando clic sobre ella) se almacene el indice de la fila (RowIndex), seria asi:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    renglon = e.RowIndex; //La variable renglon debe estar previamente declarada y ser de tipo entero
}
```

Una ves que tienes el indice de la fila que esta seleccionada solo extraes los datos del dataGridView:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string nombre;
    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1) //Esta validacion es para que no te salte error si das clic en los encabezados o en la fila de la izquierda
    {
          nombre = dataGridView1.Rows[renglon_selec].Cells["NOMBRE"].Value.ToString(); //"NOMBRE" es el nombre de la columna en mi tabla, o puedes usar el indice de la columna [indice_columna]
          txtNombre.Text = nombre; //Aqui le asignas al TextBox lo que sacaste del dgv
    }
}
```

Para los demas campos solo tienes que ir haciendo lo mismo.

Si te sirvió no olvides marcarla :D

Answer (score 0):

según entiendo deberías pasar a la variable ArticuloDGV,etc el dato de la fila que tienes seleccionada:

```
ArticuloDGV = dgvArticulos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

y así con las demás variables.
Espero que te haya podido ayudar.

Comment: Creo que es algo así, sin embargo cuando agrego esta instruccion me manda este error:  El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección. Nombre del parámetro: index

Comment: Imagino que es porque accedes a una fila que no debes. Deberías pulsar sobre la parte izquierda de la fila y que no sea el encabezado. O bien es porque aun no has creado la tabla a la cual quieres acceder.